# Combine zip archives in ANT with both filtering and case-sensativity

Tags: ant, zip

I want to combine several zip files together using ANT, but I've got three restrictions that cause the standard techniques to fail:

1. There are files (with known filenames) that I do not want included in the final archive.
2. Some of the source archives contain files with the same name, but different capitalization.
3. The machine that runs the script uses a case-insensitive filesystem.

To make my problem concrete, here's an example source archive.  I do *not* know the file names represented by `a.txt` and `A.txt`, but I *do* know the filename `b.txt`.

```
$ touch a.txt ; zip src.zip a.txt ; rm a.txt 
$ touch A.txt ; zip src.zip A.txt ; rm A.txt 
$ touch b.txt ; zip src.zip b.txt ; rm b.txt 
$ unzip -l src.zip 
Archive:  src.zip
  Length     Date   Time    Name
 --------    ----   ----    ----
        0  09-23-11 11:35   a.txt
        0  09-23-11 11:35   A.txt
        0  09-23-11 11:36   b.txt
 --------                   -------
        0                   3 files
```

And here's what I want:  (everything from the original archive except b.txt)

```
$ ant
$ unzip -l expected.zip
Archive:  expected.zip
  Length     Date   Time    Name
 --------    ----   ----    ----
        0  09-23-11 11:35   a.txt
        0  09-23-11 11:35   A.txt
 --------                   -------
        0                   2 files
```

The two techniques that I've found recommended on the internet are:

```
<target name="unzip-then-rezip">
    <!-- Either a.txt or A.txt is lost during unzip and
         does not appear in out.zip -->
    <delete dir="tmp"/>
    <delete file="out.zip"/>
    <mkdir dir="tmp"/>
    <unzip src="src.zip" dest="tmp"/>
    <zip destfile="out.zip" basedir="tmp" excludes="b.txt"/>
</target>

<target name="direct-zip">
    <!-- Have not found a way to exclude b.txt from out.zip -->
    <delete file="out.zip"/>
    <zip destfile="out.zip">
        <zipgroupfileset dir="." includes="*.zip" />
    </zip>
</target>
```

Using `unzip-then-rezip`, I loose either `a.txt` or `A.txt` because the underlying filesystem is case-insensitive and can not store both files.  Using `direct-zip` seems like the right way to go, but I have yet to find a way to filter out the files I don't want included.

I'm about to resort to creating my own ANT task to do the job, but I'd much rather use standard ANT tasks (or even ant-contrib), even if there's a performance or readability penalty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at Ant's [Resource Collections](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/resources.html#collection), especially things like [`restrict`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/resources.html#restrict) that allow you to filter files (and zip file contents etc.) in quite flexible ways.

This snippet seems to what you want (on my machine at least - OSX):

```
<project default="combine">
  <target name="combine">
    <delete file="expected.zip" />

    <zip destfile="expected.zip">
      <restrict>
        <zipfileset src="src.zip" />
        <not>
          <name name="b.txt" />
        </not>
      </restrict>
    </zip>

  </target>
</project>
```

The input file:

```
$ unzip -l src.zip
Archive:  src.zip
  Length     Date   Time    Name
 --------    ----   ----    ----
        0  09-24-11 00:55   a.txt
        0  09-24-11 00:55   A.txt
        0  09-24-11 00:55   b.txt
 --------                   -------
        0                   3 files
```

The output file:

```
$ unzip -l expected.zip
Archive:  expected.zip
  Length     Date   Time    Name
 --------    ----   ----    ----
        0  09-24-11 00:55   A.txt
        0  09-24-11 00:55   a.txt
 --------                   -------
        0                   2 files
```

Comment: While this answer is technically correct, it performs poorly when the zip files are very large (by number of entries).  I did not debug the script sufficiently to find a root cause, so I'm still open to any suggestions on this thread of thinking that anyone has.  In the mean-time I created a custom ant task, see below.

Comment: @drew What version of ant are you using?

Comment: Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.2 compiled on June 3 2011.  MacOS 10.6.8.  To give some scale, the final zip is ~12,000 files and 15MByte.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up creating a custom ANT task to solve the problem.  The task accepts nested `excludes` elements which provide regular expressions that are matched against the entires in the source zip file.

As an added bonus, I was also able address another problem: renaming zip entries using regular expressions using a nested `rename` element.

The ANT code looks something like this:

```
    <filter-zip srcfile="tmp.zip" tgtfile="target.zip">
        <exclude pattern="^b\..*$"/>
        <rename pattern="^HELLO/(.*)" replacement="hello/$1"/>
    </filter-zip>
```

The kernel of the ANT task looks something like this:

```
    zIn = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(srcFile));
    zOut = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(tgtFile));

    ZipEntry entry = null;
    while ((entry = zIn.getNextEntry()) != null) {

        for (Rename renameClause : renameClauses) {
            ...
        }
        for (Exclude excludeClause : excludeClauses) {
            ...
        }

        zOut.putNextEntry(...);
        // Copy zIn to zOut
        zOut.closeEntry();
        zIn.closeEntry();
    }
```

In my original question, I said I wanted to combine several zip files together.  This is pretty straight forward using the 'direct-zip' method in the original question.  I use this to create an intermediate zip file (`tmp.zip`) which I then use as the source to my `filter-zip` task:

```
    <zip destfile="tmp.zip">
        <zipgroupfileset dir="." includes="*.zip" />
    </zip>
```

At the moment my `filter-zip` task runs a little slower then the `zip` (assemble all the zips) task... so the performance is (probably) pretty close to ideal.  Combining the two steps together would be a nice little exercise, but not very high ROI for me.